# Как удалить n/a из значений ключей

Tags: bash, sed

Подскажите как регуляркой пройтись по файлу и удалить значение ключа = n/a (только через bash)

Файл до:

```
val1=n/a1111
val2=2222
val3=n/a
val4=11n/a
val5=n/a
```

Нужно файл после:

```
val1=n/a1111
val2=2222
val3=
val4=11n/a
val5=
```

Пробовал `sed 's:n/a::'` но он удаляет все входы *n/a* в файле.

```
val1=1111
val2=2222
val3=
val4=11
val5=
```

Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно удалить все `n/a`, которые идут после
последнего знака равенства и до конца строки, то так:

```sh
$ sed -e 's:=n/a$:=:' -- ./file.txt > ./new_file.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно - вопрос закрыт.